# Number of graphs without any isolated vertices

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, inclusion-exclusion

How many labeled graphs there are of order $n$ without any isolated vertices?

By the inclusion-exclusion principle, we have:

$$\sum_{i=0}^n (-1)^i{n\choose i}2^{n-i \choose 2} $$

But is there any closed form for it? Or is there any better solution?

Comment: What is the meaning of acronym IEP ?

Comment: To count how many graphs there are, are the vertices considered different or indistinguishable? That is, is $1-2-3$ the same graph as $1-3-2$?

Comment: @JeanMarie Inclusion-Exclusion Principle

Comment: @ajotatxe No, they are not the same... probably it would be much harder if they are indistinguishable...

Comment: Shouldn't there be a $(-1)^i$ factor in there?

Comment: @Zestylemonzi Of Course! Done!

Comment: By the way, is your question about all labeled graphs or only simple graphs?

Comment: @shn just simple. Is it easier for general graphs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The numbers are given in [OEIS A006219](https://oeis.org/A006129).  They start $$1, 0, 1, 4, 41, 768, 27449, 1887284, 252522481, 66376424160, 34509011894545, 35645504882731588, 73356937912127722841, 301275024444053951967648, 2471655539737552842139838345, 40527712706903544101000417059892, 1328579255614092968399503598175745633$$ No clean formula is given.  I found it by computing the value for $n=8$ and searching for $252522481$.  They grow approximately as $2^{n \choose 2}$

Comment: can you prove this formula please? I can't understand one moment, let n = 4, then total number of possible graphs is 64, now we should exclude all graphs with property that at least 1 vertex isolated. But, using this formula we can select 4 vertices to be isolated, for each one we can build 8 graphs on 3 others vertices. So some cases we count multiple times, for example when all vertices isolated it is 4 cases of 32. So, what is the correct rule in inclusion-exclusion formula we should apply?

Comment: No, I can't prove it.  I don't remember how I did the $n=8$ case.  For $n=4$ you can isolate a vertex by cutting all $3$ edges incident, so each vertex can be isolated in $2^3$ ways because there are $3$ other edges which might or might not be there. If you isolate two vertices this way you have eliminate $5$ edges so there are only $2$ choices.  You can't isolate three vertices without isolating all four.  This would give $64-4\cdot 8 +{4 \choose 2}2=38$  But you can also have graphs with two pairs of connected vertices, there are $3$, which gives $41$.

Comment: Then how they give this formula?) If there is no proof for that. Do you mean that I should do any case separately???

Comment: It depends whether you want an approximate or exact answer.  Often we can approximate the growth of a function more easily than we can find the exact values.  I was just reporting what I found in OEIS.  You can follow the links to see where it comes from.